# How do I create a Class Method to return a substring of an existing class field (String Type)

Tags: c++, class, unicode, substring

I am an old self taught user of C & C++, but am now getting used to Unicode Strings etc...!

Using C++ I am trying to add a method to my class to return a substring of an existing Class field. The compiler will not let me return a substring as it is "temporary".  How can I do this?, maybe within some macro conversion?

Partial Class definition:

```
#define TFTWDATA_MAXPARTS 20

class TFtwData {
private:
public:
   __fastcall          TFtwData(intiLevel, String   iPath);
   __fastcall          ~TFtwData();
   int       Level;      // Depth
   String    Path;       // Full Path of This File
   int      StartPos[TFTWDATA_MAXPARTS];
   int      Length  [TFTWDATA_MAXPARTS];
   String & GetPathPart(int i) { return Path.SubString(StartPos[i],Length[i]); } ;
};
```

The constructor will take a supplied file path, and create an array of StartPos/Length pairs defining each part of the filename.

I want to be able to create a method which will allow me to access any part.

I Could create each part as String array, but that's a waste of space.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the declaration of `String::SubString` and repeat the returning type

```
const String& GetPathPart(int i) {
  return Path.SubString(StartPos[i], Length[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Thanks for your response.

I did try this, and adding const changed my Error into a warning. The routine noe either does nothing, or crashes.

The say I see it is that the SubString function creates it's result on the Stack, which can then be immediately re-used / destroyed.

If I change the routine to save the output from SubString into a static String, everything works Ok.

The only issue with this is that the data will be over witten by the next call. I guess I could create an array of 100 static Strings and use them in rotation maybe that would work. (I guess I only need enough to handle the maximum calls within one instruction - ie a compare may use 2 calls to complete this?)

I cannot see inside the SubString method anywhere so I do not know how that works.

Any better Ideas of how to achieve this

I have many routines which manipulate strings and I want to return them without having to pass in a buffer to achieve this.

Any better Ideas of how to achieve this